# Getting ArrayLists IndexOutBoundsException

Tags: java, eclipse, scheduling

I am trying to create a process scheduler in java. I have a sample process class, and a scheduler class where I am doing the scheduling logic. I am getting error in the first line of the First Come First Server (FCFS) method.

```
Queue.add(Arriving.get(0));
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)

```
public class Scheduler {

    // I use two lists to keep track of the processes that haven't arrived and the processes in the cpu queue
    ArrayList<Process> Arriving;
    ArrayList<Process> Queue;
    Process runningProcess;
    int currentTime;
    // new process boolean used to check if a process was added to the cpu queue
    boolean newProcess;

    public Scheduler(ArrayList<Process> Queue){
        Arriving = new ArrayList<Process>();
        Queue = new ArrayList<Process>();
        for (int i = 0; i<Queue.size(); i++) {
            Arriving.add(Queue.get(i));
        }
        Sort();
        currentTime = 0;
    }

    public void FCFS(){
        Queue.add(Arriving.get(0));
        Arriving.remove(0);
        runningProcess = Queue.get(0);
        while(runningProcess.getRemainingTime() != 0){
            if (runningProcess.getRemainingTime()==0){
                Queue.remove(runningProcess);
                runningProcess = Queue.get(0);
            }

            while (Arriving.get(0) != null){
                for(Process process:Arriving){
                    if (process.getArrivalTime()==currentTime){
                        Queue.add(Arriving.get(0));
                        Arriving.remove(0);
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
                runningProcess.running();
                for(int i = 1; i<Queue.size(); i++)
                    Queue.get(i).waiting();
            }
            System.out.println(Queue.size() + " processes waiting.");
            currentTime++;
        }
    }

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Process a = new Process(1, 15, 0, 0);
        Process b = new Process(2, 9, 5, 0);
        Process c = new Process(3, 3, 8, 0);
        Process d = new Process(4, 12, 10, 0);
        Process e = new Process(5, 4, 14, 0);
        ArrayList<Process> queue = new ArrayList<Process>();
        queue.add(a);
        queue.add(b);
        queue.add(c);
        queue.add(d);
        queue.add(e);
        Scheduler run = new Scheduler(queue);
        run.FCFS();
}
        public void Sort(){
        ArrayList<Process> Unsorted = new ArrayList<Process>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Arriving.size(); i++){
            Unsorted.add(Arriving.get(i));
        }
        ArrayList<Process> Sorted = new ArrayList<Process>();
        Process someProcess;
        for(int i = 0; i<Unsorted.size(); i++) {
            someProcess = Unsorted.get(i);
            for (Process process:Unsorted){
                if (process.getArrivalTime()<someProcess.getArrivalTime())
                    someProcess = process;
            }
            Sorted.add(someProcess);
            Unsorted.remove(someProcess);
        }
        Arriving = new ArrayList<Process>();
        for (Process process:Sorted) {
            Arriving.add(process);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have in your main method, you initialize `queue`, adding instances of `Process` to it.

```
ArrayList<Process> queue = new ArrayList<Process>();
queue.add(a);
queue.add(b);
queue.add(c);
queue.add(d);
queue.add(e);
Scheduler run = new Scheduler(queue);
```

`queue` is passed into the constructor of `Scheduler`, only to be initialized again, thus removing all the instances of `Process` that were previously in it.

```
public Scheduler(ArrayList<Process> Queue) {
    Arriving = new ArrayList<Process>();
    Queue = new ArrayList<Process>(); // Change this line to this.Queue = Queue
    for (int i = 0; i<Queue.size(); i++) {
        Arriving.add(Queue.get(i));
    }
    Sort();
    currentTime = 0;
}
```

So when you try to loop through all the objects in the constructor, `Queue.size()` returns 0.

You have `ArrayList<Process> Queue` as a member of the class, although this name mirrors the local variable `Queue` that was passed into `Scheduler`.

Instead of looping through `Queue` and adding all the objects to `Arriving`, you can simply set `Arriving = Queue` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ArrayList as a queue. The test for an empty queue is `myList.isEmpty()` which you should check before accessing the elements.

Alternatively, you can use `java.util.Deque`, which returns null when you peek the head or tail of an empty deque with `peekFirst()` or `peekLast()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty list check before doing `Queue.add(Arriving.get(0));`.

That should solve the problem.

You should do get() or remove() only if something is present in List.